# location_id cannot be null while trying save using a Spring JPA 2 repository

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring JPA 2 entity class as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Hotel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "hotelId")
    @JsonProperty("hotel_id")
    private Integer hotelId;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Location.class, cascade =  CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id") 
    @JsonProperty("location")
    private Location location;
    ....
   }
```

and the Location class is given as

```
   @Entity  
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   public class Location {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer location_id;

     @Column
     @JsonProperty("latitude")
     private Double latitude;

     @Column
     @JsonProperty("longitude")
     private Double longitude;
   }
```

When I'm doing an `hotelRepository.save(hotel)` I'm getting `Column 'location_id' cannot be null`. I get the populated `Hotel` by consuming a REST web-service.

Can anyone please help me! Appreciated!

Comment: Hi Younis, have you checked hotel before saving? Is 'location_id' null in that point?

Comment: @jherranzm thanks for the reply. I just checked it, and it WAS null. Why for the life of me, is it null? The GenerationType is AUTO and the corresponding db field is auto_increment.

Comment: Hi Younis, have you saved previously the 'location' entity? Before you save the 'hotel' entity.

Comment: Hi jherranzm, you are a ray of sunshine on a cloudy day! Worked like a charm! Thanks so much!